# extracting a conditional value from a table using Selenium WebDriver VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am writing a program using Selenium on Excel VBA that extracts the daily report from a portfolio.
Normally the report will display a table like this:
[image]

Then I'll use the Full XPath Element to copy the Starting and Ending values to my spreadsheet.
The thing is that somedays there are Deposits or Withdrawals and the table will show it like this:
[image]

Since I'm creating a table where it shows the Starting Value, The Ending Value and the Deposits & Withdrawals for every day I would like to know how can I get the deposits & withdrawals amount only when is showed and when is not to display zero.

To get the Starting or Ending Value I use:

```
Dim sumtotal As Range
Set sumtotal = ActiveCell
sumtotal.Value = obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/am-page/div/div[2]/ng-include/div/section/div/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]").Text
```

I should use a conditional so if there is a Deposit & Withdrawals value then copy it using the FullXPath and if there is no Deposits & Withdrawals on the table display zero on the cell.

I just don't know how to do that or maybe I should do it in a different way.

Anyway, I appreciate any help...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, watching a tutorial on YouTube I did the following:
I used the FindElelmentByCss to refer to the table, then I used the FindElementsbyTag applied to the table WebElement previously referred so it can return all the elements with the specified tag.
Then, I applied a For each Loop to check if any of those Elements have the name Deposits & Withdrawals and what to in case it does.

```
Dim tdHeaders As Selenium.WebElements
Dim tdHeader As Selenium.WebElement
Dim divtable As Selenium.WebElement

Set divtable = obj.FindElementByCss("#tblNAV_U5632534Body > div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-4 > div > table")
Set tdHeaders = divtable.FindElementsByTag("td")

n = 0
For Each tdHeader In tdHeaders
    If n = 1 Then
        Inflows.Value = tdHeader.Text
        Exit For
    End If
    If tdHeader.Text = "Deposits & Withdrawals" Then
        n = 1
    End If
Next tdHeader
If n = 0 Then
    Inflows.Value = 0
End If
```

I have no idea if that is the best way to go so any comment would be appreciated.